# Make updates in one mysql table depending on the content of another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, A and B.

A has 'id' as primary key. B has (id, alpha) as primary key.
There is a column 'alpha' in A too. There is another column 'beta' in B.

I want to make the following query:

Update A, set A.alpha to ---> that B.alpha such that B.id = A.id and B.beta = (max(beta) for that particular id). Also, this should happen for only those A.id's whose alpha value is not equal to any of the alpha values in B for that same value of id. Not otherwise. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: So `Table A` has columns `id, alpha` and `Table B` has columns `id, alpha, beta`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the cleanest solution you get, but I believe it hits all your requirements:

```
update a, b
set a.alpha = b.alpha
where 
    a.id = b.id and
    a.alpha not in (
        select alpha
        from b b1
        where b1.id = a.id
    ) and
    b.beta = (
          select max(beta)
          from b b2
          where b2.id = a.id
    )
```